# Centralizers of completely reducible subgroups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p \geq 0$. Let $G$ be a connected reductive group defined over $k$ with $p$ good for $G$.
In what follows, I will cite results from the following two papers: Serre's "Complete reductibilite", and Bate-Martin-Rohrle's "A geometric approach to complete reducibility".
Let $\Gamma \subset G(k)$ be a closed subgroup. $\Gamma$ is said to be $G$-ir if it is not contained in any proper parabolic of $G$. $\Gamma$ is said to be $G$-cr if for any parabolic $P$ containing $\Gamma$, there is a Levi subgroup of $P$ containing $\Gamma$.

Now suppose that $\Gamma \subset G(k)$ is a closed, $G$-cr subgroup. Consider $C_{\Gamma}$, the centralizer of $\Gamma$ in $G$ (viewed as a group scheme over $k$ via the functor of points). By BMR, Proposition 3.12, $C_{\Gamma}^0$ is reductive. A vague question: is there an algebraic group-theoretic characterization of this class of subgroups?

By Serre, Proposition 3.4, one can associate to $\Gamma$ a "nice" Levi $L$ containing $\Gamma$: let $S$ be a maximal split tori of $C_{\Gamma}$ and let $L=C_G(S)$. Then $L$ contains $\Gamma$ and is minimal among all the Levis containing $\Gamma$. Moreover, $\Gamma$ is $L$-ir, and if $k$ is perfect, different choices of $L$ are conjugate by an element in $C_{\Gamma}$. As an example, suppose $G=GL_n$ and $k$ is algebraically closed, if we view the group $\Gamma \subset GL_n(k)$ as an $n$-dimensional representation of itself, then it can be decomposed into a direct sum of irreducibles. In this case, the Levi $L$ may be written in the form
$$L\cong (GL_{d_1})^{m_1} \times \cdots \times (GL_{d_s})^{m_s}$$
for integers $d_1<\cdots<d_s$ and $m_1, \cdots, m_s$, where the $d_i$'s are the dimensions of the irreducibles, and $m_i$ is the number of irreducibles of dimension $d_i$. If for each $i$, $m_{i1},\cdots, m_{it_i}$ is the partition of $m_i$ determined by the multiplicities of the irreducible summands of dimension $d_i$, then Schur's lemma implies that
$$C_{\Gamma} \cong \prod_{i=1}^s GL_{m_{i1}} \times \cdots \times GL_{m_{it_i}}.$$
For example, if the representation of $\Gamma$ is multiplicity-free, then $C_{\Gamma}=Z_L$.

Putting it in a slightly different perspective, the above shows that if one fixes a Levi $L$ of $GL_n$ and consider all possible $L$-ir subgroups $\Gamma \subset L(k)$, then up to $N_G(L)$-conjugation, there are only finitely many possibilities for $C_{\Gamma}:=C_G(\Gamma)$, which can be described in terms of partitions of integers. In particular, we see that this class of groups is independent of the group $\Gamma$ or the field $k$ we started with. Even though there can be a huge number of possibilities for $\Gamma$, its centralizer $C_{\Gamma}$ falls into a much smaller and tractable class of reductive groups.
One can also work out something similar for the symplectic groups and orthogonal groups. I wonder if there is something more general that holds for any connected reductive algebraic group.